# Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'. Working with some elements but not with others

Tags: javascript, html, dom, child-nodes

I'm creating a script that use a fetch to retrieve an external HTML, then through some operation create 2 HTMLcollection and finally iterate over them to display a div with one element from the first collection and one from the second collection.
Here some code I wrote:

```
<section id="to_take">
       <p>THE EUROPEAN PARLIAMENT AND THE COUNCIL OF THE EUROPEAN UNION,</p>
       <p>Having regard to the Treaty establishing the European Community, and in particular Article 175(1) thereof,</p>
       <p>Having regard to the proposal from the Commission,</p>
       <p>Having regard to the opinion of the European Economic and Social Committee <a href="#1" id="1back">(1)</a>,</p>
       <p>Having consulted the Committee of the Regions,</p>
       <p>Acting in accordance with the procedure laid down in Article 251 of the Treaty <a href="#2" id="2back">(2)</a>,</p>
       <p>Whereas:</p>
<ol> 
     <li>some li elements that I'm not posting because they are too much.</li>
</ol>
<p>another P element</p>
</section>
```

this is the HTML code that is taken by the script, the other document is equal, but in another language.

the script is:

```
async function request(input_1, input_2){
        var left = await fetch(input_1);
        var right = await  fetch(input_2);
        var text_left = await left.text();
        var text_right = await right.text();
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        var part_1 = parser.parseFromString(text_left, "text/html");
        var parser_2 = new DOMParser();
        var part_2 = parser_2.parseFromString(text_right, "text/html");
        var collection_1 = part_1.getElementById("to_take").children;
        var collection_2 = part_2.getElementById("to_take").children;
        display_elements(collection_1, collection_2);

    }
        function display_elements(array_1, array_2){
        var article = document.getElementById("contenitore");
        var counter = 0;
        for (var i in array_1){
            var container = document.createElement("div");
            container.appendChild(array_1.item(counter));
            container.appendChild(array_2.item(counter));
            article.appendChild(container);
            counter++;
        }
    }
```

The script is actually working well in displaying in the right page section what it must, but it has 1 strange behaviour and 1 error.
First: it takes the first element from the 2 collections, but then the script skips the second element and go to the third one and again, it takes 1 element and skip the following one.
Second: it gives me this error: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
I tried to modify some elements, but basically I don't understand why it does not work in the right way.
I tried to change the method on the collection, using While instead of for, but I don't understand the error, because it works for some element and not for others.

Comment: What is `array_1`? You never define it

Comment: sorry typo when posting the code, just fixed

Comment: Are array_1 and array_2 containing the same number of elements? Since .children is live, you may also want to check that counter is always 0 (on a phone myself so I can't check rn). You may be better using two loops, and on static collections like `part_n.querySelector("#to_take *")`

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is skipping elements, because when you do:

```
container.appendChild(array_1.item(counter))
```

...you *move* that item away from `array_1` into the container element. This means that all following items in `array_1` will move from their current index position to one less (it is a *live* collection). Yet, you increase `counter++`, so at that moment you jump over an array element which you will never visit.

Instead, don't use a counter at all, but just use `array_1.item(0)`, and loop until `array_1` is empty:

```
while (array_1.length) {
    var container = document.createElement("div");
    container.appendChild(array_1.item(0));
    container.appendChild(array_2.item(0));
    article.appendChild(container);
}
```

Just realise that you really empty the two "to_take" elements, who lose their child elements. If you don't want that to happen, then keep your code as you had it, but *clone* the elements as you do `appendChild`:

```
var counter = 0;
for (var i in array_1){
    var container = document.createElement("div");
    container.appendChild(array_1.item(counter).cloneNode(true));
    container.appendChild(array_2.item(counter).cloneNode(true));
    article.appendChild(container);
    counter++;
}
```

To protect your code from a situation where one of the arrays is shorter, or an item is `null`, add some `if` conditions:

```
var counter = 0;
for (var i in array_1){
    var container = document.createElement("div");
    if (array_1.item(counter)) 
        container.appendChild(array_1.item(counter).cloneNode(true));
    if (array_2.item(counter)) 
        container.appendChild(array_2.item(counter).cloneNode(true));
    article.appendChild(container);
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: thank you, now I cannot test this solution, but I will keep you updated

Comment: Might still fail if array_2 has less elements than array_1

Comment: Yes, @Kaiido, but the OP wrote *"the other document is equal, but in another language."*, so I think we may assume the document structure is equal, and so the two arrays have the same length.

Comment: It works, but there is an additional error, after all iterations it gives me this error: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'cloneNode' of null`

I set the counter to -1 to avoid going out of range, but it still remains, I tried to go with a while loop stopping when it reach the lenght of the HTML collection. I don't know why, I confirm that both HTML collections has same length.

Comment: That means that you have `array_1.item(counter)` (or `array_2.item(counter)`) equalling `null`. You should debug why you have a `null` there. Don't try things to get around the problem... first understand why you have a `null`. Can you confirm which line this error occurs on?

Comment: In the meanwhile I added a variant of the last code snippet that adds some `if` statements. This will just skip over any `null` situation. But it would be an indication that both arrays do not have the same length.